# is it possible to create view from custom adapter in many size?

Tags: android

For Example, like Google+ there are one big size and two small size display alternately until reach the last view. So is it possible to do this.

Like this picture:
http://upic.me/show/42297666

Google+ show each item in different size.

Thanks.

Comment: Please! This is not enough information to understand your problem

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

1) You create a layout (my_layout) take care of alignments

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:gravity="left"
 android:padding="1dp"
android:layout_gravity="left"
android:orientation="horizontal" >
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/contentImage1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    android:src="@drawable/browse_product_thumbnail" />
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/contentImage2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    android:src="@drawable/browse_product_thumbnail" />
```

2) Now write and adapter for this  and  getView() method . Something like below code

```
public class ItemListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<LaunchItem> {

private int             _resource;
private LayoutInflater  _inflater;
private static Launcher _browse;
private static final String tag = "Adapterr";
public ItemListAdapter(Launcher activity , int resourceId, List<LaunchItem> objects) 
{
        super( activity, resourceId, objects );
        _resource = resourceId;
        _inflater = LayoutInflater.from(activity);
        this._browse = activity;
}




    @Override
    public View getView ( int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent ) {


        convertView = ( LinearLayout ) _inflater.inflate( _resource, null );

        String imagePath = "";
        String name = "";
        LaunchItem item = getItem( position );


    }
```

}

You can  decide what to display and their visibility on getView .

3) Use the custom adapter in your code .

```
            List<LaunchItem> lList = new ArrayList<LaunchItem>();   
        lList.add(new LaunchItem(image1,image2 );
        ItemListAdapter  data = new  ItemListAdapter (this,R.layout.my_layout,lList);
        view.setAdapter(data);
```

-Preeya